# Biological aging interval equals Proper Time interval?

Tags: special-relativity, time, inertial-frames, observers

In special relativity does proper time interval equal biological aging interval in every inertial reference frame?

Answer (score 2):

Yes.  The observer's proper time is the time that governs all physical and chemical processes in a moving observer, including aging.

Comment: I agree, how does one get main stream science to accept it?   .